# social login in a website using a mobile app

Tags: facebook, rest, cordova, twitter

I have a website that is supporting a normal email/password authentication, as well as twitter, g+ and fb logins.
We are starting to develop a mobile app using phonegap that will talk directly to the website. 
My question is: what is the best way to secure the social logins and link them against the website? 
We are communicating with the webapps using rest services and we started implementing the oauth authentication on the app side, but is this the best way to go?